# Forms testing Angular 4

Tags: forms, angular, unit-testing

I have done a small Web App in Angular 4 and I'm now trying to test it.
Here is what I would like to test :

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" ngModel name="name" pattern=".{2,}" required #name="ngModel">
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" [disabled]="!f.valid">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
        <span class="help-block help" *ngIf="!name.valid && name.touched ">Please enter at least two characters</span>
      </form>
```

At first, I would just like to test if the form is really invalid (and then I cannot click on the submit button) if thye word entered in the input is less than 2 characters.

Here is the test code I have written

```
 beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NavbarComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should disable submit if word<2',()=>{
    const compiled = fixture.nativeElement;
    const input = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input'));
    input.nativeElement.value='b';
    input.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    //console.log(compiled.querySelector('input').textContent);
   //console.log(compiled.querySelector('.ng-valid'));
   expect(compiled.querySelector('.ng-valid')).toBe(null);

  });
```

The textContent of the input is modified properly but the form is still valid. However, when I use the webapplication, I can't submit the form is the word is less than two characters.
I feel like the word in the input doesn't really "reach" the form in the test. I've tried a lot of different things so any help would be great !

Comment: Where do you test if the word has more than 2 characters?

Comment: @onetwo12 in the html file on the input I have a `pattern=".{2,}"` which tests it and disable the submit button if the word is less than two characters. In my typescript, as I am filling the input with a one letter word, it should make the form invalid